# In ASP.Net what is the difference between Authentication in IIS and in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I worked on a ASP.Net MVC 5 web application.

My web application is using Windows authentication, and I created a virtual directory to the web application on IIS.

There is an `Authentication` icon to configure the authentication via IIS, and it contains:

- Anonymous Authentication: Enabled.
- ASP.NET Impersonation: Disabled.
- Forms Authentication: Disabled.

So where is the Windows authentication?

Now in `web.config` in find:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
   <!--<deny users="?" /> i know that to deny Anonymous -->
</authorization>
```

So what is the difference between the authentication settings in IIS and authentication in `web.config`? I can do what I want using `web.config` so why the IIS authentication configurations?

Comment: Windows Authentication is an OS component you need to manually enable. Some Windows editions do not contain it at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can add/remove some security features in the add enable/disable windows features in the control panel at the IIS section:

[image]

Now, when you change the authentication type in the IIS, those changes are persisted in the web.config file, for windows authentication the option is basic authentication:

[image]

PD: My OS is in spanish, so sorry for that.

Regards,